# htaccess rewrite rule does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am facing problem with rewrite rule in htaccess file. Please help.

This is my current htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /product-project/
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I want to create a rewrite rule such as "product/category/id" should redirect to "product/profile?profile_id=id". For this I have used

```
RewriteRule ^product/.*/(.*)$ product/profile?profile_id=$1 [L,R]
```

which is working fine in some way.

1st problem ->  It is redirecting properly, but URL also changes. It should stay as "product/category/10", if I use the id as 10. But when I use this, it is redirecting properly, but URL changes to "product/profile?profile_id=10". I read somewhere to use [L,P] instead of [L,R] , but it is giving as Server error.

2nd problem -> Now I want to create a new rewrite rule such as "product/id" should also redirect to "product/profile?profile_id=id". For this I have used

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ product/profile?profile_id=$1 [L,R]
```

Now this is not working & showing server error

3rd Problem -> Can I also create a new rewrite rule such as "/id" should also redirect to "product/profile?profile_id=id". Is this possible ?

4th Problem -> Can I also create a new rewrite rule such as "/id1/id2" should also redirect to "product/profile?profile_id=id1&serial_id=id2". Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want please check.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1/$2?profile_id=$3
```

for two id's

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1/$2?profile_id=$3&id=$4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it..

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not working..When I enter localhost/product-project/product/10 -> it should redirect to localhost/product-project/product/profile?profile_id=10. &   When I enter localhost/product-project/10 -> it should also redirect to localhost/product-project/product/profile?profile_id=10